# What is essence of this dialogue between two men and meaning of off slant?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> One day President Harper met this young Oriental on the campus, stopped to chat with him for a few minutes, and asked what had impressed him as being the most noticeable characteristic of the American people.
>
> "Why", the Chinaman exclaimed, "the **queer slant** of your eyes. Your eyes are **off slant**!" What do we say about the Chinese? We refuse to believe that which we do not understand.

What does the words in bold means ?

Thank You

Comment: You may want to research the meaning of each of those words in a dictionary, and read the paragraph following your last sentence.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to understand that caucasians make disparaging remarks about asians because their eyes have [epicanthic folds](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Asians-have-different-eyes), which makes their eyes seem to be [slanted](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slant?q=Slant).

This chinese guy knows this and turns the idea round, sayin that caucasoid eyes have a strange slope- implying that asian eyes are normal.

[Queer](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/queer?q=Queer) in this context means strange or unusual. In recent years it is used more about homosexuals.

Off is used to mean slightly incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The author want us to introspect how we look towards our limitations. That is generally we think that Chinese peoples eyes are off slant but he says it just how you look.

Comment: Hi, Shantanu, just dropping in as part of the community review, but I wanted to ask: Is there something in your answer that you think sets it apart from the answer given by JavaLatte? I'm probably just being dense and not seeing it, but if you could please help elaborate, I think it would help make this answer more accessible (for me, at least). Nothing personal, just part of the review queue. Thanks and welcome to the English Language Learners Stack Exchange!